# Angular --prod flag break up component style sheets

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, angular-components

I'm have simple component which is used to show if data are rendered ASC or DESC. That simple component have some logic inside but for this case more important, it have it's own styleUrls. Unfortunately with --prod flag that styles are not build correctly.

**My component looks like this:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sort-header, [sort-header]',
    templateUrl: 'sort-header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sort-header.component.scss'],
})
export class SortHeaderComponent implements OnInit {/* Component BODY */}
```

if we look at styles it's very simple:

```
.sort-header-container {
    & a {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        &:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 2px;
            right: -19px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-family: monster;
            line-height: 1;
            padding: 0 4px;
            speak: none;
            -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
        }
        &.sort-asc:after {
            content: '\E0AA';
        }
        &.sort-desc:after {
            content: '\E0A8';
        }
    }
}
```

**Results of commands:**

If I run command:

```
ng build recommender-portal --prod --aot --output-hashing=none --vendor-chunk --sourceMap=true
```

icon it should show is broken and if I inspect HTML / CSS on page content looks like this:
[image]

If I run exact same command without --prod:

```
ng build recommender-portal --aot --output-hashing=none --vendor-chunk --sourceMap=true
```

icon is not broken and if I inspect HTML / CSS on page it looks like this:
[image]

**Conclusion**

Few things that come in my mind of possible root cause:

- I upgraded Angular to 8 recently which may break something
- sort-header.component.scss is not mentioned in angular.json but I believe it only belong to component as I don't want it to be in main styles

However I didn't manage to find anything yet, maybe I just missed something obvious just because of looking wrong way so I will be happy for any advise or additional questions which can point me the right way.